# Python - OTRS REST/SOAP API - python-otrs

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, otrs

Using a rest/soap API like [python-otrs](https://github.com/ewsterrenburg/python-otrs) or pyotrs is possible to close a ticket?

using python-otrs i try and receive a error:

```
otrs.client.SOAPError: TicketUpdate: Ticket->StateID or Ticket->State parameter is invalid! (TicketUpdate.InvalidParameter)
```

The code i try is:

```
from otrs.ticket.template import GenericTicketConnectorSOAP
from otrs.client import GenericInterfaceClient
from otrs.ticket.objects import Ticket, Article, DynamicField, Attachment

server_uri = r'https://www.example.com'
webservice_name = 'GenericTicketConnectorSOAP'
client = GenericInterfaceClient(server_uri, tc=GenericTicketConnectorSOAP(webservice_name))

# user session
client.tc.SessionCreate(user_login='user', password='pass')

t_upd = Ticket(State='closed',StateID='3')
client.tc.TicketUpdate(3657,ticket=t_upd)
```

where 3657 is the id of the ticket.

Thanks,
jp

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct state name is `closed successful` but you don't need to ad both the name and the ID, just one of them should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the key exactly used in the backend. You sould able check/match in the admin state  aswell. The value of parameter should always match to the unique key used in the status table.